# Test concurrent call of the same function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, concurrency

I have a function:

```
var inRendering = false;
function render() {
  if (inRendering) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  } else {
    inRendering = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      longAction();
      inRendering = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I have to unit-test it. To test a situation of concurrent call of `render`.

Help me, please? Is such concurrent call ever possible in JavaScript? Thanks.

P.S. I wrote a test which obviously doesn't work (see comment): https://gist.github.com/kuraga/b0aa3d66fc0620f03b11

Comment: You need to write an async test.

Comment: What do you mean, @SLaks, exactly? And my attempt of test is asynchronous (but without WebWorkers)

Comment: You're not really trying to test concurrent calling of the same function.  JS is single-threaded so you can make recursive calls to the same function but apart from a recursive call, the first call of a function will finish before another can start.  You want to test if the outer function (render) is called again before the inner function from the first call to render is called.  To test this, you would mock requestAnimationFrame so that you can control this during your test.

Comment: also, you have a bug... you want inRendering = true; requestAnimationFrame(function () { ... inRendering = false; });  You need to signal that a render has been requested when you call requestAnimationFrame rather than when you get called from rAF.

Comment: @neonstalwart yeah, you're right about bug. Big thanks! Do you propose totally mock `requestAnimationFrame` (without calling real `requestAnimationFrame`)? P.S. I know "IO operations and exceptions" may cause next animation frame (before function finishes) but I don't know how to use this here exactly...

Comment: I'm suggesting `var originalRAF = requestAnimationFrame; requestAnimationFrame = mockRAF /* something you control during the test */; doTest(); requestAnimationFrame = originalRAF;`

Comment: @neonstalwart I know how to mock I just asked about content of `mockRAF`. Ok, I'll try myself. Thanks for idea!

Answer (score 1):

you can use async module, specifically [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) in order to run two functions in parallel

for example:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        // run your function once
    },
    function(callback){
        // run your function the second time
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! But "Note: if your tasks do not use any timers or perform any I/O, they will actually be executed in series." So, it's another problem, maybe the same as in my attempt. I'll try in a day. Thanks, @nir-levy